# Installing windows 10 with an external screen

Tags: windows, installation, display, external-display

Basically I want to install this new windows 10 tehnical preview edition on my laptop, but the problem is that I have a broken laptop screen so I connected my laptop to a different monitor.
I pressed the F- keys before my current windows load and I could see the page where are boot options. 
Question: May I see the installation on my external screen?
I googled it, but still couldn't find an answer, hope anyone of you know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Windows on a laptop using an external monitor (main display broken)](http://superuser.com/questions/294061/installing-windows-on-a-laptop-using-an-external-monitor-main-display-broken)

Comment: Yes you can, I tried it on 8.1, so it should work on Win10. In my case I had  to press the Fn- combination again after exiting BIOS, and a few times afterwards since it restarts automatically.