# How do i install win10 on a broken screen laptop?

Tags: windows-10, laptop

I am installing windows 10 on laptop which have a broken screen. Can i move the installation window to the secondary screen that I have connected? 
I have tried to move the screen around with no success also I have tried other button combinations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Windows on a laptop using an external monitor (main display broken)](https://superuser.com/questions/294061/installing-windows-on-a-laptop-using-an-external-monitor-main-display-broken)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes,** you can easily install your windows on your broken laptop screen.
just by attaching the external display connected through the HDMI or VGA cable.
after setting up this.

Go to the keyboard and type windows+p button then press down key two times and then hit enter.

cheers,